# SmoothBivariateSpline gives unexpected answer

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate a 2d unstructured grid using scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline. I'm afraid I have not understood how it is supposed to work.

I've tried with a very simple example:

```py
from scipy import interpolate

x = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
z = [-0.07453796, -0.10857792, -0.07307213, 0.01813757, -0.31634891, -0.47235507, -0.33198942, -0.28530956, -0.26995915, -0.40618327, -0.0950876, -0.18871505]

xy_func = interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline(x, y, z, kx=1, ky=1, s=0)
print(xy_func.ev(0, 1), xy_func.ev(1, 0), xy_func.ev(1, 3))
```

I've visualized the result and it is obvious that it is incorrect. I also evaluated the result on some of the data points since it should be clear what the output should be. From the print I expected to get the output "-0.10857792, -0.31634891, -0.28530956", but I got the result "-0.1390947215 -0.272092075 -0.16190767".

Where am I off?

Comment: Bug report (pretty old!) on SciPy's github site: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2167

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems:
If you allow a curvier shape by increasing i.e. kx=2 and ky=3, you already get a much better fit of your predictions.

[image]

However, because SmoothBivariateSpline doesnt like the vertical nature of your test data, you will not get very good results anyway. If you change x so that it increments more evenly i.e. (x=range(len(x)), it looks much better.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "vertical nature of your test data", I think you might have misunderstood (or maybe I have). As I understand each x and y pair have a corresponding z value, for example x=3 and y=1 have z = -0.16190767. This means that in your plot, each green dot have an elevation in the third dimension (into/out from the screen).